# Select top 3 per field after group MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with fields like "servicereqesttype", "zipcode", "date"

I want to fing the 3 most common "servicerequesttype" per zipcode for a specific day.

```
db.event.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        creationdate: "2011-01-01"
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        zipcode: "$zipcode",
        servicerequesttype: "$servicerequesttype"
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            zipcode: "$zipcode",
            servicerequesttype: "$servicerequesttype"
        },
        zipcode: {
            $first: "$zipcode"
        },
        servicerequesttype: {
            $first: "$servicerequesttype"
        },
        count: {$sum: 1}
    }
},
{
    $sort: {
        "zipcode": -1,
        "count": -1
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        zipcode: "$zipcode",
        servicerequesttype: "$servicerequesttype",
        count: "$count"
    }
}
])
```

now all I have to is to select only 3 per zipcode and I need some help, maybe I have to use $bucket or $map...

Answer (score 0):

```
db.event.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        creationdate: "2011-01-01"
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        zipcode: "$zipcode",
        servicerequesttype: "$servicerequesttype"
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            zipcode: "$zipcode",
            servicerequesttype: "$servicerequesttype"
        },
        zipcode: {
            $first: "$zipcode"
        },
        servicerequesttype: {
            $first: "$servicerequesttype"
        },
        count: {$sum: 1}
    }
},
{
    $sort: {
        "zipcode": -1,
        "count": -1
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        zipcode: "$zipcode",
        servicerequesttype: "$servicerequesttype",
        count: "$count",
        arrayOfTypes: "$array1",
        arrayOfIncidents: "$array2"
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$zipcode",
        arrayOfTypes: {
            $push: {type: "$servicerequesttype", count: "$count"}
        }
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: "$_id",
        array: {
            $slice: ["$arrayOfTypes", 3]
        }
    }
},
{
    $sort: {
        "_id": -1
    }
}
])
```